# How to pass null to an Observable with nullable type in RxJava 2 and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I initialize my variable like this:-

```
 val user: BehaviorSubject<User?> user = BehaviorSubject.create()
```

But I can't do this. IDE throws an error:-

```
user.onNext(null)
```

And doing this, IDE says u will never be null:-

```
user.filter( u -> u!=null)
```

Comment: You can't - even in Java, `.onNext(null)` will evaluate to `.onError(new NullPointerException(...))`.

Comment: In RxJava 1 it was possible. But in 2 it is not.

Comment: BTW: Your code is not even compiling. Please post only valid code in here. You can edit the post to fix this.

Comment: @guenhter The code doesn't have to compile if the question is how to make the code compile.

Comment: RxJava implements the reactive streams specification which does not support null values. You can use https://github.com/gojuno/koptional to wrap the values. Includes filters for RxJava

Comment: @nhaarman the question is not how to make it compile. It is how to pass null

Comment: One possible workaround would be to use `AtomicReference(null) ` vs `AtomicReference(User)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you very much for all your answers but I ultimately went with this solution:-

```
class UserEnvelope(val user:User?) {}
```

And using this in the observables.

This best suited my requirements.

I am new to Kotlin so I don't know how to use Optionals. But from what I understand, I would have to typecast it to User type everytime I need to observe the values right?

Comment: I like this approach, it is straight forward and clean.

Answer (score 28):

As [Guenhter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45294695/675383) explained, this is not possible. However, instead of proposing the null-object pattern, I'd recommend an implementation of the `Optional` type:

```
data class Optional<T>(val value: T?)
fun <T> T?.asOptional() = Optional(this)
```

This makes your intent much clearer, and you can use a destructuring declaration in your functions:

```
Observable.just(Optional("Test"))
  .map { (text: String?) -> text?.substring(1)?.asOptional() }
  .subscribe()
```

Using the null-object pattern here can cause more bugs than it solves.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the cleanest way to do it (even if I don't really like Optionals :) ).

Comment: A "complete" implementation of `Optional` (with methods like `java.util.Optional`) is pretty short: https://gist.github.com/ephemient/2dec1165b7993e6a6cd7cdfa005fe277

Comment: @ephemient interesting approach!

Comment: Could someone explain this code?  I don't understand `data class Optional<T>, and also fun <T> T?.asOptional() = Optional(this).  It looks like he is creating a data class called "Optional", but what does the <T> after it do?  Does the class "Optional" take on the same type of it's parameter, the "value" of type "T?"?

Answer (score 11):

If you use rxkotlin/rxjava 2.0 (I assume so) than the answer is: you can't. The reason is explained here.

This is a break of the interface. Have a look at the `Observable` Interface

```
public interface Observer<T> {

    /** ... */
    void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d);

    /** ... */
    void onNext(@NonNull T t);

    /** ... */
    void onError(@NonNull Throwable e);

    /** ... */
    void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d);

    /** ... */
    void onNext(@NonNull T t);

    /** ... */
    void onError(@NonNull Throwable e);
...
```

The `@NonNull` will be considered by the Kotlin compiler and therefore you CAN'T pass null.

Even if you could, the `onNext` would immediately throw an error:

```
@Override
public void onNext(T t) {
    if (t == null) {
        onError(new NullPointerException("onNext called with null. Null values are generally not allowed in 2.x operators and sources."));
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

If you really need such a thing as `null` you have to fake it. e.g. by creating a static object of `User` which represents your `null`-element.

e.g.

```
data class User(val username, val password) {

    companion object {
        val NULL_USER = User("", "")
    }
}
...
val user = BehaviorSubject.create<User>()
...
user.onNext(User.NULL_USER)
...
user.filter { it !== User.NULL_USER }
```

But if is somehow possible, try to avoid the `null` concept and maybe think of another solution where this isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

To implement the solution mentioned in the [nhaarman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/675383/nhaarman)'s answer, you can use the util class `Optional` ([doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Optional)) from the Android SDK which was added in **API level 24**.

If your app's `minSdkVersion` less than 24 then you still need to implement it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Since RxJava 2 does not support *null* values, there are some other acceptable solutions you can use:

- Work with a custom or third party wrapper library of Optionals like some of the posted answers suggest. When I got rid of Java in favour of Kotlin, Optionals went away in the same package since Kotlin per se supports nullability as part of its type System. Just by this change the code was much more clearer, and I personally don't want to get Optionals back in my code as long as I can avoid them.
- Emit `Any` class instances with your subject type. For example you could create an `Empty.INSTANCE` enum class which would emulate the *null* value and then filter by the enum class.
- The last one is the one I use and prefer being a variant of the previous solution and is based on specialisations. Our friends of JetBrains always emphasise that classes are very cheap in Kotlin, so this would be a quick example to distinguish logged users and not logged ones:

  ```
  abstract class SessionUser
  sealed class LoggedUser(val username: String, val password: String) : SessionUser()
  sealed class LogoutUser : SessionUser()

  private val user = BehaviorSubject.create<SessionUser>()
  private val loggedUser = 
     user.filter { it is LoggedUser }.cast(LoggedUser::class.java)

  fun login(username: String, password: String) {
     user.onNext(LoggedUser(username, password))
  }

  fun logout() {
     user.onNext(LogoutUser())
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken an approach similar to `Optional<User>` and `UserEnvelope`. I make a simple `User` class and a `ReifiedUser` class that inherits from it. The `User` class has a `companion object` that has a NONE instance. The `BehaviorSubject` is instantiated with the `User.NONE` instance. It looks something like this:

```
open class User {
    companion object {
        val NONE = User()
    }
}

class ReifiedUser(
        @field:JsonProperty(J.FirstName) val firstName: String,
        @field:JsonProperty(J.LastName) val lastName: String
) : User()
```

My `BehaviorSubject` is instantiated like this:

```
val activeUser: BehaviorSubject<User> = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(User.NONE)
```

And wherever I need to use `activeUser` I either `flatMap` it to `Observable.empty()` if it's NONE or just figure out what it is and what to do in the subscriber.

I don't like mixing java `Optional` with kotlin nullable because mixing `map` and `let` gets really confusing and ugly. This way it's very obvious what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes more sense to write a container class such as `Result`. An example of that would be

```kotlin
data class Result<T>(value: T?, error: Throwable?)
```

Usage

```kotlin
Observable.create { observer ->
   upstreamService.listen(object: UpstreamListener {
     onSuccess(data: User) {
       observer.onSuccess(Result(data))
     }
     onError(exception: Throwable) {
       observer.onSuccess(Result(null, exception))
     }
   }
}
```